# What's the baseball bat for? (seen in CRS-8 berthing NASA TV broadcast)

Tags: iss, nasa, berthing

Watching the CRS-8 Berthing live broadcast on [NASA TV](https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/index.html) I noticed a baseball bat resting on top of a console in the front left part of the room, so I took some screenshots.

Looking closer, it seems to be about a meter or two away from a large, delicate-looking model of the International Space Station.

Is this part of NASA internal humor?

[image: NASA CRS-8 berthing baseball bat larger]

[image: NASA CRS-8 berthing baseball bat full screen]

Comment: A [Clue stick](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cluestick)?

Comment: it's a version of the hard reset tool
https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/6c/35/fa/6c35fa73e0b8db2d7213453a4d65e108.jpg

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The baseball bat is for "Attitude adjustment", apparently :)

[image]

Source: [Arstechnica photos of ISS control room](http://arstechnica.com/science/2013/07/how-nasa-steers-the-international-space-station-around-space-junk/)

(ADCO=Attitude Determination and Control officer)

Here's a better pic of the bat from the Twitter:
[image]

Comment: Mentioned [here](http://www.rocketsfromcassiopeia.com/2012/10/sharing-the-view-3/) along with some better pics of the bat. Note the comment below (from [Mark Passy](http://pages.erau.edu/~ericksol/projects/issa/mc_ops.html)) indicating that it's been at NASA for quite some time

Comment: Aha, I see! Legacy technology keeping the newer technology in line. The article is good, and thanks @Richard for the background too.

Comment: Is there something else there for the five knuckle shuffle? ;)

Comment: The tweet speaks for itself! The Ars Technica [two page article](http://arstechnica.com/science/2013/07/how-nasa-steers-the-international-space-station-around-space-junk/) is a good read as well.

Comment: In the article linked by @uhoh you can also see Mjölnir, [here](http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/IMG_6723-Version-2.jpg) (middle right)

Comment: ...and a wooden mallet belonging to someone called "THOR"... (Thermal Operations and Resources)

Comment: [Mjölnir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir) is the name of Thor mallet ;)

Comment: @JFL Andy is pulling your mallet - and also posted the link in the answer originally.

Comment: Reminds me of the peanuts they keep stashed at JPL for mission-critical moments.

Answer (score 3):

Besides being the "Attitude Control Device" in MCC-Houston, the bat belonged to one of out top ADCOs who is a big baseball fan.

Comment: It's great to know that attitude control was done with a personal touch ;-)